# How would I deserialize a dynamic complex json object

Tags: python, json

So right now I have a modular system for interacting with my `Game()` object, which handles all data storage for the game. Right now I'm working on a system for saving all properties of the Game object into a json file. I already figured out to serialize the entire object using

`save_json = json.dumps(G.__dict__, indent=4, default=lambda o: o.__dict__)`

My problem now is deserializing and because my Game object is modular, I don't know what kind of nested objects will be inside the object, and I need a dynamic system for loading them. On top of everything, some properties of the Game object are dictionaries, some are lists, and some are just variables.

All solutions I've looked up end up hard coding the deserialization into the `__init__` of the objects, which doesn't work for me because my system is modular.

Comment: `g = Game(); g.__dict__.update(json.loads(save_json))` ... **might work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is really what `pickle` is designed for

```
save_data = pickle.dumps(g)

...

loaded_g = pickle.loads(save_data)
```

if however you are set on using json... **maybe** the following would work

```
g = Game()
g.__dict__.update(json.loads(save_game))
```

Comment: Trying the json.loads doesn't work, it just gives me an object with dictionaries instead of objects, I've been trying to avoid using pickle of security reasons but I guess I can give it a try.
Now that I'm thinking about it, pickle could also be used to prevent people from cheating their saves.

Comment: @EpicPuppy613 what exactly is your security concern? Look, writing a general, JSON-based serialization framework isn't exactly trivial. There are existing third-party libraries, like [`marshmallow`](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/) or [`pydantic`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/). But honestly, for what you seem to be doing, I don't understand why `pickle` doesn't work.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga according to the python wiki, pickle is not secure and can lead to arbitrary code execution when unpickling although I don't really know how someone could get a malicious pickle onto someone's computer.

Comment: there are plenty of ways to verify the pickle... from actual encryption to checksums... its main risk is executing pickles that originate from untrusted parties (for example you would not want to allow someone to "upload" pickles to your website... )

Comment: @EpicPuppy613 but why do you care? Will you be unpickling files that someone else is providing? This is generally only a problem if you are unpickling files received as input, say, you have some server that accepts arbitrary binaries from HTTP requests. If someone can manipulate a pickle file that is part of your game, they can *probably just use Python to execute arbitrary code anyway*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga like I said, I don't really know how someone could get a malicious pickle onto someone's computer. The game really isn't an online game, but online features might be implemented later

Comment: As @juanpa.arrivillaga says: pickled files or json files are just data.  Data is not malicious unless it is executed as code, or the data readers call other code when reading the data.  You generally have control of that.